# Cakephp REST integration with iPhone app

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm developing backend system for iPhone app providing JSON data for each request for iPhone app. This is Cakephp based backend system and I was wondering if there was a good Cake way to receive POST request?

I understand using Router::mapResources(), Router::parseExtensions(), requestHandler component, Xml and Javascript helper is the correct way of creating RESTful application? If so, I was wondering how we could set them up to accept POST requests and potentially XML and/or JSON aswell.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a good Cake way to receive POST request?

send a POST request to the correct url, and you can process it as normal. The POST data is in $this->data in the controller.

> If so, I was wondering how we could set them up to accept POST requests and potentially XML and/or JSON aswell.

XML and JSON are not in the same category as POST. Read about REST setup [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1238/REST)

Comment: are you sure that it will come through $this->data even if we don't follow cake's naming conventions for post key names? ie. data['value']. I know we can do this with get variables with using things like $this->params['url']

Comment: well, you do have to follow the convention (why would you not want to?) for the data to be in $this->data. Or you can always access $_POST